# Given the length of 3 sides of a triangle, find the missing angles

Tags: c, algorithm, geometry

I want to calculate the missing angles of a triangle where the length of 3 sides are given.
This code is giving -1.#IND00 output value for all three angles for any line distance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    float l1, l2, l3, a1, a2, a3;
    printf("Enter the line length of three lines of triangle: ");
    scanf("%f%f%f", &l1, &l2, &l3);
    a3 = acos( ((l1*l1)+(l2*l2)+(l3*l3))/(2*l1*l2) );
    a1 = asin( (l1*sin(a3))/l3 );
    a2 = acos(-1) - a1 - a3;
    printf("Three angles are: %f %f %f", a1, a2, a3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The wrong formula (`((l1*l1)+(l2*l2)+(l3*l3))/(2*l1*l2)`) generates a number outside the valid range for `acos()`

Comment: Note that you should check that all values are positive and that no sum of 2 sides is less than the third side to validate the input.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the angle *a*<sub>3</sub> is cos<sup>−1</sup>((*l*<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>+*l*<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>−*l*<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup>) / (2*l*<sub>1</sub>*l*<sub>2</sub>)), not cos<sup>−1</sup>((*l*<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>+*l*<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>+*l*<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup>) / (2*l*<sub>1</sub>*l*<sub>2</sub>)).